# I'm trying to get a new piece of hardware to respond. The instructions given are sparse. I need some help getting my code to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I feel like I'm doing this correctly but the device isn't responding.  I've tried sending each byte individually, encoding them, and sending as a bytearray.  This machine does NOT seem to respond.

Packet Structure
A packet consists of several data fields as described below:
STX - 1 byte
LENGTH - 1 byte
COMMAND - 1 byte
DATA[n] - n byte
ETX - 1 byte
CHECK_SUM - 1 byte

- STX 0x02 hex
- LENGTH Length of (COMMAND+DATA) = 1+n (bytes)
- COMMAND Command between Host and Guest
- DATA[n] Data fields ( )
- ETX 0x03 hex
- CHECK_SUM (~SUM) or (0xFF – SUM) ,where SUM is; SUM = Length of (LENGTH + COMMAND + DATA[n])

This is the "Start Command" required to start up the machine
STX - 0x02
LENGTH - 1 byte
COMMAND - 0x01
DATA[n] - n byte
ETX - 0x03
CHECK_SUM  - 1 byte

DATA [0]: Count start method
0: Count starts only by PC
1: Count starts by PC or User

After the start command it's supposed to respond back with additional data but I'm getting nothing.  Any help would be appreciated.
**Original code**

```py
    import serial
    import sys
    # import time
    # import struct

    def CreateByteArray():    
        print('    Creating bytearray...')
        packet = bytearray()
        packet.append(0x02)
        packet.append(0x02)
        packet.append(0x01)
        packet.append(0x00)
        packet.append(0x03)
        packet.append(0x03)
        # print(packet)
        # print('Length of bytearray: ', len(packet))
        return packet

    def printPacket(packet):
        print('   ',packet)
        print('    Len of packet', len(packet))

    try:
        print("Init serial port...")    
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600,timeout=0,write_timeout=0)
        ser.flushInput()
        print(ser)
        print("   Is serial open?", ser.isOpen())
        print("   Serial Name?", ser.name)
        print('')

        print('Build packet...')
        packet = CreateByteArray()
        print('   ',packet)
        print('    Len of packet', len(packet))
        print('')
        print('Writing packet...')
        ser.write(packet)

        # packet = bytearray()
        # packet.append(0x02)
        # ser.write(packet)

        # packet = bytearray()
        # packet.append(0x02)
        # ser.write(packet)
        # printPacket(packet)

        # packet = bytearray()
        # packet.append(0x01)
        # ser.write(packet)
        # printPacket(packet)

        # packet = bytearray()
        # packet.append(0x01)
        # ser.write(packet)
        # printPacket(packet)

        # packet = bytearray()
        # packet.append(0x03)
        # ser.write(packet)
        # printPacket(packet)

        # packet = bytearray()
        # packet.append(0x03)
        # ser.write(packet)

        # print('')
        # print(len('0'.encode('utf-8')))
        # print('0'.encode('utf-8'))

        # print('write STX')
        # print(ser.write(b'\x02'))
        # ser.write('2'.encode('utf-8'))
        # print('write length...')
        # ser.write(b'\x02')
        # ser.write('2'.encode('utf-8'))
        # print('write command...')
        # ser.write(b'\x01')
        # ser.write('1'.encode('utf-8'))
        # print('write data...')
        # ser.write('1'.encode('utf-8'))
        # print('write ETX...')
        # ser.write(b'\x03')
        # ser.write('3'.encode('utf-8'))
        # print('write checksum...')
        # ser.write(b'\x03')
        # ser.write('3'.encode('utf-8'))

        # print('check is_waiting...')

        print('')
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            print('while loop...')
            while(ser.in_waiting>0):
                print('reading byte...')
                data = ser.read(1)
                print('data ', data)
        else:
            print('No byte found in buffer...')


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    print('')
    print("Closing serial port...")
    ser.close()
    print(ser)
```

I've removed the comments and kept only the code with the bytearray
**Updated code**

```py
    import serial
    import sys
    # import time
    # import struct

    def CreateByteArray():    
        print('    Creating bytearray...')
        packet = bytearray()
        packet.append(0x02) # STX
        packet.append(0x02) # Length of command and data
        packet.append(0x01) # Commmand
        packet.append(0x00) # Data
        packet.append(0x03) # ETX
        packet.append(0x03) # Checksum (SUM = Length of (LENGTH + COMMAND + DATA[n])
        return packet

    def printPacket(packet):
        print('   ',packet)
        print('    Len of packet', len(packet))

    try:
        print("Init serial port...")    
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600,timeout=0,write_timeout=0)
        ser.flushInput()
        print(ser)
        print("   Is serial open?", ser.isOpen())
        print("   Serial Name?", ser.name)
        print('')

        print('Build packet...')
        packet = CreateByteArray()
        print('   ',packet)
        print('    Len of packet', len(packet))
        print('')
        print('Writing packet...')
        ser.write(packet)

        print('')
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            print('while loop...')
            while(ser.in_waiting>0):
                print('reading byte...')
                data = ser.read(1)
                print('data ', data)
        else:
            print('No byte found in buffer...')


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    print('')
    print("Closing serial port...")
    ser.close()
    print(ser)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "this machine does seem to respond" ... often instrumentation must have a setting set to enable serial communication ... try and just read one character after you write

Comment: The command "ser.in_waiting" is always zero.  I'll try reading a single character after the right to see if it responds with something.

Comment: "in_waiting" is still zero.  I tried sending a bytearray with a single byte and a single byte by itself.

Comment: you could try and end the command with `\r` a lot of interfaces wait for `\r` before they try to process the data

Comment: I tried the following: ser.write("\r".encode('utf-8')).  It's still not returning anything.

Comment: The values in your "start command" packet are questionable, so whatever else might also be incorrect in your program does not matter.  The "length" and data byte are questionable. The "checksum" appears to be wrong; the definition you posted is nonsensical.  BTW binary packet interfaces such as this one do not expect `\r` line termination nor any *"encoding"*.

Comment: Are you speaking to my python code?  Or the description above?

Comment: Nothing in PySerial says I have to send the "\r" when doing a write.

Comment: If you can't tell I'm new to serial communication.  If you can recommend a book, article, anything for me to read and learn I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Your "packet" descriptions are repetitive and unclear.   The only values you have clearly posted follow the `packet = bytearray()` statement in the code.

Comment: many many many scientific instruments that use serial interfaces read line or wait for soem other terminal character ... certainly not all ... but many do ...  another thing to check is if its RS232 or RS485(or some other variant (ie SDI-12) ... if you check for in_waiting immediatly after the command it might not be there (often times it takes anywhere from a few miliseconds to several seconds for a device to respond to a command) so you could try adding a delay ... are you sure it expects 9600 baud?

Comment: As already mentioned, your checksum value, `packet.append(0x03) # Checksum (SUM = Length of (LENGTH + COMMAND + DATA[n])`, does not adhere to the previous description. I've never seen a "count" used as a "sum", but regardless, you fail to apply the **one's complement** aspect of the (poorly written) definition, *"CHECK_SUM (**~SUM**) or (**0xFF – SUM**) ,where SUM is ..."*.  Note that this "checksum" only aids in confirming byte alignment, and does nothing to ensure/confirm message integrity.  IMO this is a ill-defined and not robust message protocol.  What device is this for?

Comment: unfortunately there are too many variants of protocols and devices to help you trouble shoot this problem, without significantly more detail (ie whatever manual may exist)... although there's plenty of chance you are calculating checksum or packet length wrong somehow

Comment: I appreciate everyone chiming in. We've reached out to the vendor of the hardware to get more information.